# Why is the monthString returning null

Tags: java, string

I'm parsing a bunch of ints from strings that were 'substring-ed' from a simpleDateFormat string. For some reason that I haven't been able to figure out the String monthString keeps coming up NULL, I dont see why.

I have created the string in another function call and when I pass it to the next function the string then becomes NULL

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton start, highscore, help, stoppen;
    private int yearNumber, monthNumber, dayNumber, daysInMonth;
    private String monthString, yearString, dayString;

    private String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());



public void go(){
    setMonthString();
    getDayString();
    getYearString();
    getDayNumber(dayString);
    getYearNumber(yearString);
    getMonthNumber(monthString);
    getDaysInMonth(monthString);
    makeThisMonthFolders();
    maakComponenten();
    maakLayout();
    toonFrame();
}

private void makeComponent() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    String dayString = timeStamp.substring(0,2);

    System.out.println("Today is day " + dayNumber + " of the month");

    String monthString = timeStamp.substring(3, 5);

    System.out.println("Month string: " + monthString);


    start = new JButton("Move Folders"){
        {
            setSize(150, 75);
            setMaximumSize(getSize());
        }
    };
    start.addActionListener(this);
}

private String setMonthString(){
    String monthString = timeStamp.substring(3, 5);

    if(monthString.substring(0,1) == "0"){
        System.out.println(monthString.substring(0,1));
    }
    /*if(monthString.substring(0, 1) == "0"){
        monthString = monthString.substring(1);
    }*/
    return monthString;
}


public int getMonthNumber(String monthString){
    System.out.println(monthString);
    monthNumber = parseInt(monthString);
    return monthNumber;
}
```

}

```
Here is the null return from a test and the error codes thrown:

Today is day 0 of the month
Month string: 07
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.company.MainMenu.getMonthNumber(MainMenu.java:123)
at com.company.MainMenu.go(MainMenu.java:37)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
7
null

ERROR AT 123 references:
System.out.println(monthString);
monthNumber = parseInt(monthString); // this line
return monthNumber;
```

Comment: `monthString.substring(0,1) == "0"` - no, use `equals`

Comment: @ScaryWombat indeed, that is a mistake, but that is not causing the problem here.

Comment: @NDC your code uses variables that don't exist. please post your actual code, not something that is "somewhat similar"

Comment: Okay I changed it to equals now. Is now updating the string, however for some reason will not save the monthNumber variable value when I parse it from the month  String

Comment: The return value of `setMonthString();` is not being assigned to anything

Comment: @NDC setters are supposed to set the value of a variable that 'll contain the value after the method is finished executing. local variables only exist during execution of the method

Comment: But in your go method, you pass variables that don't exist as parameters to methods, so how on earth did you ever get that to compile?

Comment: sorry, i added the code now with the declared variables that I was passing to the method calls

Comment: and where is `parseInt` defined?

Comment: The Code which is accepting the monthString is null, because the line which calls getMonthNumber(monthString); is passing the instance variable of Object which is null

public int getMonthNumber(String monthString){
    System.out.println(monthString);
    monthNumber = parseInt(monthString);
    return monthNumber;
}

Update this code to accept the proper value, by storing the month value inside the instance variable monthString

Comment: You shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`, since they're obsolete. Use the newer Java Date and Time API from the `java.time` package.

Comment: And don't call methods functions. Call them methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you have called the function `getMonthNumber(monthString);` But you've not declared it globally. You need to declare the `String monthString = timeStamp.substring(3, 5);` outside the `setMonthString()` and then you will able to get the monthString value as needed.

I've posted below sample code of your's example so you can understand it better way.

```java
public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton start, highscore, help, stoppen;
    private int yearNumber, monthNumber, dayNumber, daysInMonth;
    private String yearString, dayString;

    private String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


public void go(){
    String monthString = getMonthString();
    getDayString();
    getYearString();
    getDayNumber(dayString);
    getYearNumber(yearString);
    getMonthNumber(monthString);
    getDaysInMonth(monthString);
    makeThisMonthFolders();
    maakComponenten();
    maakLayout();
    toonFrame();
}

private void makeComponent() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    String dayString = timeStamp.substring(0,2);

    System.out.println("Today is day " + dayNumber + " of the month");

    String monthString = timeStamp.substring(3, 5);

    System.out.println("Month string: " + monthString);


    start = new JButton("Move Folders"){
        {
            setSize(150, 75);
            setMaximumSize(getSize());
        }
    };
    start.addActionListener(this);
}

private String getMonthString(){
    String monthString = timeStamp.substring(3, 5);

    if(monthString.substring(0,1) == "0"){
        System.out.println(monthString.substring(0,1));
    }
    /*if(monthString.substring(0, 1) == "0"){
        monthString = monthString.substring(1);
    }*/
    return monthString;
}


public int getMonthNumber(String monthString){
    System.out.println(monthString);
    monthNumber = parseInt(monthString);
    return monthNumber;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works. Would it be better to write a separate function that will return the monthString and pass it the returned value of the simpleDateFormat as a parameter to the method? I'm a novice but would'nt it be better to keep that out of a global scope?

Comment: Yes, You can make it better by Creating the simple architecture of your program.
I've updated the answer with the return of month.